# Animate sprites using drawableAnmiation

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a design question so I don't start off on the wrong way. I am planning to have a sprite where it animates moving and I want to move this sprite around (changing position once every second).

I noticed that some tutorial talk about having a game loop,, onDraw on Canvas, bitmap ..etc

However, I am thinking of using drawableAnimation where  I specify the set of images to load in xml and call start on it. Then I can just draw at the position required every second ( no loop, it is more like listener that gets called every sec from different process).

Do you forsee an issue? Any problem with above method

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is a real question. I mean there could be an issue. There could be many. DrawableAnimation is memory inefficient especially for large framecount, large sized frames. The DrawableAnimation takes care of the loop you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawable Animation requires a fixed frame animation. Think of it like a flip book. The drawable would have to be the entire size of your canvas and your sprite would have to be prerendered on top of some transparent background to achieve your affect. It also would require a large amount of texture memory depending on the size and number of frames.

The "game loop" as you stated is sort of what Android already provides in a way. Inside of the standard canvas setup you have your "main Thread". So with an entity like a `Handler` you could tick frames if you like.

i.e.

```
Handler handler;
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(bundle);
handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       boolean isLastFrame = drawFrame();
       if (!isLastFrame) {
           handler.postDelayed(this, ONE_SECOND_MILLIS);
       }
   }
});
```

This is not the greatest really either.

You could also encapsulate your sprite inside a `View` or own custom `Drawable` and inside your `onDraw()` method, you would update your canvas.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // clear canvas
  mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
  // Draw current
  mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  canvas.drawRect(rect, mPaint);
}

public void moveSprite() {
  rect.offset(3, 3);
  invalidate();
}
```

You could also, if using a `View`, use an `ObjectAnimator` to translate the View from position (x1, y1) to (x2, y2).

```
public void moveTo() {
  if (!moveNeeded) {
    return;
  } 
  View view  = getMyView();
  view.animate().x(1).y(1).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator a) { }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator a) {
    }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator a) {
      moveTo();
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator a) {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. However, I still didn't get why is it bad to use drawableanimation..According to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html , you can have an imageview and assign drawable animation. This will simulate the Sprite walking. Then I can apply translate animation like in your code above. Is this bad?

Comment: That use is not bad. There wasn't enough context to give a definitive answer. Like i have found that if you have a 100 frame Drawable then that could cause problems. But if its a loop that gets paused and restarted, that seems fine. It may drop frames though

Comment: Then let me give enough context. Sorry  I was not aware it was lack of info. It will be sprite dancing while walking. So I will use 5 frames for dancing and it is looping. For the walking, it will be just translate animation.  Howevere there will be many sprites on the screen....Its ok?

Comment: Sounds fine. It's all up to if the decice can support it, which sounds reasonable